# Second Linear Difference Equation

Tags: linear-algebra, finite-differences

$$y_{t+2}-2y_{t+1}+y_t=-15$$
Getting $y^{h}_t$ is fairly simple, and I get $$(C_1+C_2)1^t$$
However, getting $y^{p}_t$ is a bit harder, and requires "guessing" as our professor says. I have been "guessing" for $$y^{p}_t=A$$ $$y^{p}_t=At$$ However, the solution is supposedly $$y^{p}_t=At^2$$ $$y^{p}_{t+1}=A(t+1)^2$$ $$y^{p}_{t+2}=A(t+2)^2$$

But can anyone tell me how $$At^2$$ turns into $$A(t+2)^2$$

Thanks!

Comment: The same way that $t$ turns into $t+2$. If $y_t=At^2$, then $y_{t+2}-2y_{t+1}+y_t=A(t+2)^2-2A(t+1)^2+At^2=2A$.

Comment: $At+2A$ is turned into $A(t+2)$ by adding an additional $A$. But I don't see the connection for $At^2$

Comment: Could you explain more, please?

Comment: Someone that could answer this?